# AUTOCOMPLETE extender

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to use Autocomplete Extender in my Project but its not working and I am using Vs2008 .net framework 3.5
and also it gives me error for grid-view paging that source is not available 
this my .aspx code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtsearch" runat="server" Width="158px" CssClass="text"
     Height="22px" ontextchanged="txtsearch_TextChanged"/>

 <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" 
    ServiceMethod="GetFilterCategoryName" CompletionSetCount="1" CompletionInterval="10" 
    EnableCaching="true" MinimumPrefixLength="1" TargetControlID="txtsearch" 
    UseContextKey="true">
 </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

this is my Axpx.cs code

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
public static List<string> GetFilterCategoryName(string prefixText)
{
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnStr"].ConnectionString);
   conn.Open();
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Question from quick_search where Question like @Name+'%'", conn);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", prefixText);
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   da.Fill(dt);
   List<string> answer = new List<string>();
   for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
       answer.Add(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: did you get any error?

Answer (score 0):

Add a script Manager to the aspx file.

Try like this

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods = "true"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtsearch" runat="server" Width="158px" CssClass="text"               Height="22px" ontextchanged="txtsearch_TextChanged"/>

<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="GetFilterCategoryName" 
    MinimumPrefixLength="1"
    CompletionInterval="0" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" 
    TargetControlID="txtsearch"
    ID="autoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected = "false">
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

**COde Behind:**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]

public static List<string> GetFilterCategoryName(string prefixText)
{
   SqlConnection conn = new sqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnStr"].ConnectionString);
   conn.Open();
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Question from quick_search where Question like @Name+'%'", conn);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", prefixText);
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   da.Fill(dt);
   List<string> answer = new List<string>();
   for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
     answer.Add(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
   }
   return answer;
 }
```